# How to force google chrome to show svg instead of downloading it

Tags: google-chrome, svg

After installing inkscape I cannot show my local svg in chrome, it wants to download it instead. How to change this ?

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark (you're really not giving enough information)... Start -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program. Find `.svg`, click Change Program.